# Double quote in JavaScript string

Tags: javascript, html

How can I include a double quote in a JavaScript string to be shown in the browser?

I am working on my JavaScript homework and I have to include double quotes in the middle of my list as shown below:

```
if (i == 0) {

   error +=  "<li> this is not the name "....." </li>\n"
}
```

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Use single quotes.

```js
error += '<li> this is not the name "....." </li>\n';
```

Or escape the double quotes.

```js
error += "<li> this is not the name \".....\" </li>\n";
```

Answer (score 8):

Use single quotes as your string delimiters:

```
if (i == 0) {
   error += '<li> this is not the name "....." </li>\n'
}
```

If you have single quotes in the string, delimit it with double quotes.

If you have double quotes in the string, delimit it with single quotes.

If you need to use both types in the string, escape whatever delimiter you have chosen by prefixing it with a `\`.

Answer (score 6):

Consider to use the default entity

```
 &quot;
```

Comment: That won't work because the author is asking about a text region in a JavaScript string.  Even it was an HTML region in a JavaScript you wouldn't need entities.  Only for actual HTML

Comment: The string is obviously intended to generate some html fragment. And in this context it WORKS definitely (checked with jsfiddle). It is the askers choice to decide between the proposed options

Answer (score 1):

```
error +=  "<li> this is not the name “.....” </li>\n"
```

Or, if you use a variant of English where single quotation marks are the norm, as usual in British English,

```
error +=  "<li> this is not the name ‘.....’ </li>\n"
```

Using proper punctuation marks, you won’t encounter problems with the quoting conventions of JavaScript. Computer languages use [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) quotes, human languages don’t.

Just make sure your document is properly encoded (both [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) and [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) would do here) and the encoding is properly declared.