# Escaping single quote and double quote in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Double quote in JavaScript string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10055773/double-quote-in-javascript-string)

```
var array=["famous quote by Shakespear is",""to be or not to be""]
```

How do I escape the blockquote in the second element of the array which uses `"` for delimiting elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can escape with a backslash or use single quotes around the string:

```
var array=["famous quote by Shakespear is","\"to be or not to be\""];
var array=["famous quote by Shakespear is",'"to be or not to be"'];
```

Single and double quotes are interchangeable as long as you pair them correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Use a backslash:

```
var str = "famous quote by Shakespear is, \"to be or not to be\"";
var str = 'famous quote by Shakespear is, \'to be or not to be\'';
```

Or just mix the types of quotes:

```
var str = "famous quote by Shakespear is, 'to be or not to be'";
var str = 'famous quote by Shakespear is, "to be or not to be"';
```