# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting when use below jQuery code. I don't understand what is the problem is?

```
$("<table cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="ms-rteTable-default"><tbody><tr>
  <td class="ms-rteTable-default" style="width: 50%;"></td></tr></tbody></table>")
 .appendTo("#Business_x0020_Benefits_7c71784a-a647-4338-a871-27a49740ee27_$TextField_inplacerte");
```

Comment: Holy cow. It's impossible to understand something. Just format it properly.

Comment: If you have a good number of these types of strings you might want to think about using html partials and just load them in (thru ajax or other methods) when needed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Double quote in JavaScript string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10055773/double-quote-in-javascript-string)

Comment: now I am getting error at `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #Business_x0020_Benefits_7c71784a-a647-4338-a871-27a49740ee27_$TextField_inplacerte`

Comment: I updated my answer. you can't use $ in your id.

Answer (score 6):

You must `escape` quotes (`"`) inside strings in JavaScript:

```
// This is WRONG!
$("<div class="foo">bar</div>");

// This is correct.
$("<div class=\"foo\">bar</div>");
```

See? Even the StackOverflow syntax highlighter tries to help you :)

Comment: Or just use single quotes if the string is going to contain double, or vise versa.

Answer (score 3):

`$("<` you are starting your statement with the same quotes you're using inside the html.

change that to this:

```
$('<table cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="ms-rteTable-default"><tbody><tr>
  <td class="ms-rteTable-default" style="width: 50%;"></td></tr></tbody></table>')
 .appendTo("#Business_x0020_Benefits_7c71784a-a647-4338-a871-27a49740ee27_$TextField_inplacerte")
```

Using a single quote string literal is acceptable and makes it easier to manage if you're using double quotes inside the statement. If you have single quotes in there, you'll need to escape them with \' the same way the other answers are saying. Andrew's answer is perfectly valid as well. It just means you'll have to escape everything.

**EDIT**

You're getting a syntax error because that $ in your ID. you can't use that symbol in an html id. See this post: [Which characters are valid in CSS class names/selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-selectors)

Comment: now I am getting `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #Business_x0020_Benefits_7c71784a-a647-4338-a871-27a49740ee27_$TextField_inplacerte` this error.

Comment: You can't use $ in your id.

Answer (score 3):

It's just a syntax error, you have to escape your `"` with `\"`