# How do I style this span?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
var replacedString = element.innerHTML.replace(selectedString, "<span>" + selectedString + "</span>");
```

If I do `"<span style="color: red">"` then it will end up reading the quotes wrong and not work.

Comment: in javascript `'` and `"` are equivalent (no special meaning to either like in other languages) ... then, there's escaping \\` \"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Double quote in JavaScript string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10055773/double-quote-in-javascript-string)

Comment: isn't anybody going to point out that adding inline styles is bad practice?

Answer (score 2):

Either escape the quotes or use single quotes:

```
"<span style='color: red'>"
```

Personally I prefer using a combination of double/single quotes as it's more readable.

Answer (score 2):

Use `'` or escape with `\"` to enable string inside string.

So you can write `"<span style=\"color: red\">"` or `"<span style='color: red'>"`

Here's [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h65Luenc/1/).

Comment: I find `'<span style="color: red">'` to be the cleanest

Comment: @ashwell `'<span style="color: red">'` and `"<span style='color: red'>"` are equally clean. Whichever you should pick, is mostly a matter of personal preference!

Comment: I personally prefer: "<span style='color: red'>" :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use single quotes:

```
var replacedString = element.innerHTML.replace(selectedString,
    '<span style="color: red">' + (selectedString) + '</span>');
```

**TLDR**: In JavaScript you can always use both either 'single qotes' or "double quotes" for literal strings. Contrary to for instance C#, that only allows double, or SQL, which only allows single quotes. I actually often wondered why this was in the past. Webwork requires a lot of thought already, and this results in yet another choice you have to make... more ambiguity...

However one day I realized these two options DO allow you to pick 'the-other-one' when you have to type a string that contains either a single or double quote within it. That is because once you pick a quote opening character you have the use the same one to close. So `"this does not work'`:).

For that reason you can just type `"this doesn't work"`, and then the `'` in `don't` suddenly is NOT a problem anymore. Equally, using `'I say: "go learn ecmascript 6!"'` solves the issue with using double quotes inside a string. In my book think this is exactly the reason why they added this option in JavaScript.

In HTML attribute values can also be surrounded by [either single or double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373074/single-vs-double-quotes-vs). However using double quotes is seen in the wild a lot more, and also happens to be advised in [Google's HTML/CSS styleguide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/htmlcssguide.xml?showone=HTML_Quotation_Marks#HTML_Quotation_Marks) so therefore for your case I would pick single quotes for the outer string.

**Get hip**: Note that in the new JavaScript - [Ecmascript6](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/getting-started-with-es6-%E2%80%93-the-next-version-of-javascript) - there is even a third option. You can now use these quotes: **``** (called backticks):

```
`I say: "Don't use ES5 unless you have to"`
```

But the main advantage of backticks is that they specify a 'template string'. In a template string you can embed one or more variables in your string without manual `+`-ing. Instead you use `${..}` syntax, which is a more readable and less error prone.
Or, looking at the OP's question, you can now write this.

```
let replacedString = element.innerHTML.replace(selectedString,
    `<span style="color: red">${selectedString}</span>`);
```

ES6 is supported in some browsers already, most notably Chrome, though it's not quite fit for production just yet (unless you use a [transpilation tool](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=let%20replacedString%20%3D%20element.innerHTML.replace(selectedString%2C%20%20%60%3Cspan%20style%3D%22color%3A%20red%22%3E%24%7BselectedString%7D%3C%2Fspan%3E%60)%3B)).

Answer (score 0):

You could also use String.raw. It uses backticks for specifying the literal.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw

Comment: This is only supported since ES6 and not sufficiently supported for a simple task like this. Also, tildes aren’t used as delimiters, but backticks.

Comment: Corrected to backtick. Just specified that its possible in case you end up doing a lot of escaping or manual correction.

Answer (score 0):

## Four easy ways to put quotes inside a JavaScript string :

#### To produce a string with value `<span style='color: red'>` :

You could use double quotes on the outside and single ones on the inside :

```
"<span style='color: red'>"
```

You could use single quotes for both, and escape those on the inside :

```
'<span style=\'color: red\'>'
```

#### To produce a string with value `<span style="color: red">` :

You could use single quotes on the outside and double ones on the inside :

```
<span style="color: red">'
```

You could use double quotes for both, and escape those on the inside :

```
"<span style=\"color: red\">"
```