# Double nested quotes

Tags: javascript, string, quotation-marks

I have this line of code

```
formsParent.innerHTML = "<p style = 'color: black; font-family: "Times New Roman" font-size: 2em'> Order submitted. Thank you for ordering! </p>"
```

The first quote is for the `innerHTML` property. Next is the properties inside the `style` attribute of the `<p>` element, and finally I need another quote inside this for the `font-family` property with a value that has multiple words so it also needs quotation marks. There are only *""* and *''*, and using double quotes for the font-family throws an error. How do I use quotes inside quotes inside quotes?

**EDIT: This is NOT a duplicate of the [Double quote in JavaScript string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10055773/double-quote-in-javascript-string). Stop flagging this!**

In the above question, the OP asks for single-nested quotes - single quotes isnide double quotes was the answer or vice versa.

In my question, I ask for double-nested quotes - [quotes] inside [quotes] inside [quotes]. My question is an extra layer of quotes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Double quote in JavaScript string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10055773/double-quote-in-javascript-string)

Comment: @scraaappy this is not a duplicate of your linked question because that was putting quotes inside quotes. I am doing this one more time - Double nested quotes, if you will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you'd need to escape the `quotes`:

```js
formsParent.innerHTML = "<p style='color: black; font-family: \"Times New Roman\"; font-size: 2em'> Order submitted. Thank you for ordering! </p>";
```

But, in such cases it's better to use the `backtick` to contain the `innerHTML` value, thus you'd never need to escape the `apostrophes` nor the `quotes`:

```js
formsParent.innerHTML = `<p style='color: black; font-family: "Times New Roman"; font-size: 2em'> Order submitted. Thank you for ordering! </p>`;
```

Comment: Thank @ths. I completely forgot about escaping characters! Can you help me explain why this is not a duplicate of the other question?

Comment: it may be duplicate of other post, but your issue seems to be pretty basic.

Comment: That post is just two pairs of quotes. Mine involves the need of three pair of quotes.

Comment: In general, knowing how to escape special chars is a basic and a fundamental task for a programmer/developer.

Comment: I forgot about escaping characters because I don't use them that often. Do you suggest I delete the question?

Answer (score 1):

The best option here would be to escape the quote chars:

```js
formsParent.innerHTML = "<p style=\"color: black; font-family: 'Times New Roman' font-size: 2em\"> Order submitted. Thank you for ordering!</p>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```js
document.getElementById('formsParent').innerHTML = `<p style = 'color: red; font-family: "Times New Roman" font-size: 2em'> Order submitted. Thank you for ordering! </p>`
```

```html
<div id="formsParent">
```