# How an I fix nested quatation marks in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

My JavaScript is like this:

```
var contentItem = '<a onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'find-a-doctor', 'appointment', 'Appointment from Home');" class="waves-effect waves-dark">Make an Appointment</a>';
```

Quotation marks above seems wrong. How do I fix this?

Comment: By attaching the event listener using Javascript instead of an HTML attribute

Comment: Use `\'` to nest quotes

Comment: Not a good question, but see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52525674/double-nested-quotes

Comment: @freedomn-m There exist error  `Uncaught ReferenceError: ga is not defined`

Answer (score 1):

You could use ``` `` ``` (backquotes or backticks), *e.g.*:

```
var contentItem = `<a onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'find-a-doctor', 'appointment', 'Appointment from Home');" class="waves-effect waves-dark">Make an Appointment</a>`;
```

Comment: There exist error : `Uncaught ReferenceError: ga is not defined`

Answer (score 1):

Inline JS will cause all kinds of issues. Instead you could adopt a modern approach and use an event listener:

```js
// Create your item and add it to the page
var contentItem = '<a class="waves-effect waves-dark">Make an Appointment</a>';
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', contentItem);

// Cache the element you added and add an event listener to it
// that calls handleClick when clicked
const wavesEffect = document.querySelector('.waves-effect');
wavesEffect.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);

// Now your call to `ga` is much cleaner
function handleClick(e) {
  console.log('send', 'event', 'find-a-doctor', 'appointment', 'Appointment from Home');
  // ga('send', 'event', 'find-a-doctor', 'appointment', 'Appointment from Home');
}
```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: ga is not defined

Comment: That means that you've defined `ga` out of scope, which is a separate issue. The code itself is now working.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code.

```js
var contentItem = '<a onclick="ga(\'send\', \'event\', \'find-a-doctor\', \'appointment\', \'Appointment from Home\');" class="waves-effect waves-dark">Make an Appointment</a>';
```