# Change Class Content to href

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div class="container">
    <span class="text1">test</span>
    <span class="text2">test</span>
</div>
```

I want to change "text2" to a href in a javascript inside my function like this:

```
var x=document.getElementsByClassName("text2");  // Find the elements
x.innerHTML="<a href='https://test.com'>test</a>";    // Change the content
```

so the content of "text2" changes to a hyperlink called "test" which refers to "https://test.com"

Comment: So, to clarify, you want to remove the `<span class="test2">test</span>` element and replace it with a new element: `<a href="https://test.com">test</a>`? Your code above is appending an `a` tag within the `span`. Is this what you don't want?

Comment: Replace the quotes like this `x[i].innerHTML="<a href='https://test.com'>test</a>";` and be sure `i` has a value.

Comment: What is `i`???? You have nested quotes.

Comment: @zOwN There’s an obvious syntax error. That’s not “working great”.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52525674/double-nested-quotes

Comment: i want to replace the content of <span class="text2">test</span> (which is "test") with <a href="https://test.com">test</a>

Comment: Why do you need JS for such a simple task?

Comment: Spectric because this is only a small part of my whole js???? why should i post my entire js code if it isnt needed? why do comment things which dont help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure which approach you need. So here are both:

### HTML

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="text1">test</span>
  <span class="text2">test</span>
</div>
```

### Approach A - Replace the inner html of the target

```js
document.querySelector(".text2").innerHTML = "<a href='https://test.com'>test</a>";
```

### Approach B - Replace the Span with Anchor

```js
var target = document.querySelector(".text2");
if (target) {
  var anchor = document.createElement("a");
  anchor.setAttribute("href", "https://www.test.com");
  anchor.innerHTML = target.innerHTML;
  target.replaceWith(anchor);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like so:

```js
var element = document.querySelector(".text2"); // Find the first element with the class text2
element.innerHTML = "<a href=\"https://test.com\">test</a>"; // Change the content including all HTML elements that might be in there to the value specified escaping the " character
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <span class="text1">test</span>
    <span class="text2">test</span>
</div>
```

the problem was you didn't escaped the " character
you can do it also without the escaping like that:

```js
var element = document.querySelector(".text2"); // Find the first element with the class text2
element.innerHTML = "<a href='https://test.com'>test</a>"; // Change the content including all HTML elements that might be in there to the value specified
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <span class="text1">test</span>
    <span class="text2">test</span>
</div>
```