# How to resolve "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, syntax-error

I've recently built a site that houses multiple videos. All was working well until yesterday, but I realized some of the clickable videos I have are no longer clickable.

I'm receiving the error, Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list in multiple lines and was wondering how I could resolve the issue?

Here is the code for which I am receiving the error for -

```
    
    var myvideo30 = $("");
    
    $("#click30").click(function() {
        //Get rid of that old HTML content
        $("#video-slider").empty();
        
        //Bring in the new content!
        $("#video-slider").append(myvideo3);
    
        $("#paul-4")[0].load();
    
        $("#paul-4")[0].play();
    });
```

There is also a snapshot of the code for reference [here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czPff.png)

And the direct site can be accessed [here.](http://ftp.life/landing.html)

Any advice and/or solutions are greatly appreciated, thank you very much!

Comment: Has nothing to do with that code. Has to do with the fact you have nested quotes. So the code you cut out of `var myvideo30 = $("");` is the cause

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52525674/double-nested-quotes

Comment: Thank you for the resource!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just read the doc, you cannot use jquery directly, you must wait for it to be loaded

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var myvideo30 = $("");
    
    $("#click30").click(function() {
        //Get rid of that old HTML content
        $("#video-slider").empty();
        
        //Bring in the new content!
        $("#video-slider").append(myvideo3);
    
        $("#paul-4")[0].load();
    
        $("#paul-4")[0].play();
    });
});
```

[official documentation](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Then the next error is generated here

```
var myvideo30 = $("<video id='paul-4' src='Caryatid (Duhaupas) (2016) - video loop.mp4' playsinline controls controlsList="nodownload" autoplay muted loop></video>");
```

Just replace double quote by simple around `nodownload`

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, I really appreciate it! What exactly do you mean by replace the double quote by simple around nodownload?

Comment: I mean replace double quote by single quote around nodownload... so `"nodownload"` became `'nodownload'` ...

Comment: I've just added and it fixed the issue entirely! Your help is much appreciated! Bless!

Comment: You sill have to remove `<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>` it is not working and jQuery is already include by anther line, from cloudflare. Not a blocking bug but producing error logs. Also a bug in `function showDivs`

Answer (score 0):

Um? Isn't it clear? JQuery import is missing, and all the errors are generated from JQuery statements.

I don't use JQuery much but I guess $ is used when you use JQuery.

[image]

Comment: That syntax error wouldn't stem from missing jQuery though

Comment: I'm quite new to JQuery so it wasn't obvious to me! Thank you for your response. How would I resolve is missing and in turn resolve the Syntax Error messages?

Comment: Try adding this to your head tag

```<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>```

Or may be before you close your body tag

Comment: I've included this, but the syntax error still persists unfortunately!