# How do I save a JSON string in JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, json

String1, below, is valid JSON string I have as verified [here](https://jsonlint.com/). However if I put quotes around it and put it in a JavaScript file I get an error - *unterminated string constant*

```
let json_string = "insert string1 below here";
```

Comment: JSON = JavaScript Object notation, it is a string representation of a JavaScript object.  When you are writing Javascript, then you want to use the curly braces and key:property pairs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Double quote in JavaScript string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10055773/double-quote-in-javascript-string)

Answer (score 1):

Usually for this approach, you would want to export some constant

```
export const JSON_STRING = // .... stuff
```

For multiline strings, you would want to try using the new template strings in JS. Just add a backtick before and after the string

```
export const JSON_STRING = `
  {
    "foo": bar
  }
`
```

Finally, you might consider not storing it as a string. Just write it as normal JSON and then when/if you need to stringify it call [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

```
export const JSON_DATA = { ... }

// some other place
let data_as_string = JSON.stringify(JSON_DATA);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the backtick character (`) to enclose the string, instead of the regular single/double quotes:

```
let json_string = `
[{
"link": "https://www.hsph.harvard.edu/nutritionsource/healthy-eating-plate/",
"image": "https://i.imgur.com/xoqLsJq.png",
"title": "Harvard has a nutrition plate and food pyramid",
"summary": "Harvard nutrition experts created these tools to make healthy eating easy.",
"tag": "Diet",
"domain": "hsph.harvard.edu",
"date": "Jan 01, 2018",
"upvotes": "100"
}, {
    "link": "https://www.weforum.org/agenda/2017/06/changing-the-way-america-eats-moves-and-connects-one-town-at-a-time/",
    "image": "https://i.imgur.com/wSpfyPZ.jpg",
    "title": "9 lessons on longevity from 5 blue zones",
    "summary": "In certain parts of the world people live abnormally long with good health.  They are known as the blue zones.",
    "tag": "Health",
    "domain": "weforum.org",
    "date": "June, 2017"
}]
`
```

When you enclose a string with backticks, it becomes a "Template string" or a "template literal".  More info here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: Can you explain why this works ( it does )?  Why is my string not valid?

Comment: The newline character causes the break in syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Use string literal with backticks (`) . You won't have this problem with quotes and/or newlines.

Comment: Can you explain why this works ( it does )?  Why is my string not valid?

Comment: The reason it is not working is because regular javascript strings must be terminated before the next newline character. For backticks it's not the case.

Comment: Oh... the new line character.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In JS to make multiline string you have to put "\" at end of every line OR use new "`" introduced in es6. With back tick, "`", you don't need to put "\" at the end of every line.

Also there are two ways to declare string using quotation mark. " vs '.

In your example you have same quotation marks all over. Instead use single quotation mark for full string, and double quotation mark to declare json keys.

Answer (score -2):

The problem in your code is the newline character. It causes the break in the syntax of your string.

[Backticks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) (`) are the solution for your problem. You can use them to make to make multi-line strings.

See example here:

```
var string = `string text line 1
string text line 2`
```

Comment: Answers containing only links to an external site (even if it is official documentation) should be avoided. Please add some explanation/code to improve your answer.