# How to add fmt:message into .html()

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

My problem is I'm not able to put `<fmt:message key="agentIndex.label.renewalBonus" />` inside

```js
$(”#plan1RenewalBonus“).html();
```

because of the Asterisk (") problem.

I hope it could be

```js
$(”#plan1RenewalBonus“).html("<fmt:message key="agentIndex.label.renewalBonus" />");
```

anyone have solution for this issue?

Comment: What's the "Asterix (`*`)" problem?  Or did you mean due to the double quotes (`"`)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Double quote in JavaScript string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10055773/double-quote-in-javascript-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either escape the double quotes within the string (`\"`) or use single quotes. 
Also, the quotes in your JQuery selector are invalid. `”` != `"`

Corrected code:

```js
$("#plan1RenewalBonus").html('<fmt:message key="agentIndex.label.renewalBonus" />');
```